# Stack Overflow Error when getting integer size?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, matrix-multiplication

As part of a class code project, part of the assignment is to construct an algorithm that will multiply two matrices using the Strassen method.

I have created the algorithms necessary to do so, however I am getting a Stack Overflow error on a getSize() call. Any help with figuring out why this is would be appreciated.

I have not appended all code, just that which pertains to the question.

```
    // CODE CALLING THE MULTIPLICATION
    Matrix m = new Matrix(Integer.parseInt(size.getText()), 20);
    Matrix m2 = new Matrix(Integer.parseInt(size.getText()), 20);
    Matrix m3 = m.strassenMult(m2);

    // THE MATRIX CLASS
    public class Matrix {

    private int[][] vals;
    private int size;
    private boolean stable = false;
    private long time;

    // Constructor for known data
    public Matrix(int[][] vals) {
    this.vals = vals;
    this.size = vals.length;
    stable = true;
    }

    // Constructor for matrix with random size, if bounds = 0 it is empty
    public Matrix(int size, int bounds) {
    this.size = size;
    vals = new int[size][size];
    stable = true;
    if (bounds != 0) {
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                int x = rand.nextInt();
                x = x % bounds;
                vals[j][i] = x;
            }
        }
    }
    }

    private Matrix add(Matrix m2) {
    ///////////////////////// THE ERROR IS ON THE BELOW LINE
    int n = m2.getSize();
    int[][] newVals = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            newVals[i][j] = vals[i][j] + m2.getVal(i, j);
        }
    }
    Matrix sum = new Matrix(newVals);
    return sum;
    }
    private Matrix subtract(Matrix m2) {
    int n = m2.getSize();
    int[][] newVals = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            newVals[i][j] = vals[i][j] - m2.getVal(i, j);
        }
    }
    return new Matrix(newVals);
    }


    // The strassen multiplication algorithm
    public Matrix strassenMult(Matrix m2) {
    int n = m2.getSize();
    int newSize = n / 2;
    // initialize new sub-matricies
    Matrix a11 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix a12 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix a21 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix a22 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix b11 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix b12 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix b21 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix b22 = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix aResult = new Matrix(newSize, 0);
    Matrix bResult = new Matrix(newSize, 0);

    // divide existing matries into the sub-matricies
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newSize; j++) {
            a11.set(i, j, vals[i][j]); // top left
            a12.set(i, j, vals[i][j + newSize]); // top right
            a21.set(i, j, vals[i + newSize][j]); // bottom left
            a22.set(i, j, vals[i + newSize][j + newSize]); // bottom right

            b11.set(i, j, m2.getVal(i, j)); // top left
            b12.set(i, j,m2.getVal(i, j + newSize)); // top right
            b21.set(i, j, m2.getVal(i + newSize, j)); // bottom left
            b22.set(i, j, m2.getVal(i + newSize, j + newSize)); // bottom right
        }
    }
    // Calculating p1 to p7:
    ////////////////////////////////// ERROR IS CALLED BY THIS METHOD
    aResult = a11.add(a22);
    bResult = b11.add(b22);
    Matrix p1 = aResult.strassenMult(bResult);
    // p1 = (a11+a22) * (b11+b22)

    aResult = a21.add(a22); // a21 + a22
    Matrix p2 = aResult.strassenMult(b11); // p2 = (a21+a22) * (b11)

    bResult = b12.subtract(b22); // b12 - b22
    Matrix p3 = a11.strassenMult(bResult);
    // p3 = (a11) * (b12 - b22)

    bResult = b21.subtract(b11); // b21 - b11
    Matrix p4 = a22.strassenMult(bResult);
    // p4 = (a22) * (b21 - b11)

    aResult = a11.add(a12); // a11 + a12
    Matrix p5 = aResult.strassenMult(b22);
    // p5 = (a11+a12) * (b22)

    aResult = a21.subtract(a11); // a21 - a11
    bResult = b11.add(b12); // b11 + b12
    Matrix p6 = aResult.strassenMult(bResult);
    // p6 = (a21-a11) * (b11+b12)

    aResult = a12.subtract(a22); // a12 - a22
    bResult = b21.add(b22); // b21 + b22
    Matrix p7 = aResult.strassenMult(bResult);
    // p7 = (a12-a22) * (b21+b22)

    // calculating c21, c21, c11 e c22:
    Matrix c12 = p3.add(p5); // c12 = p3 + p5
    Matrix c21 = p2.add(p4); // c21 = p2 + p4

    aResult = p1.add(p4); // p1 + p4
    bResult = aResult.add(p7); // p1 + p4 + p7
    Matrix c11 = bResult.subtract(p5);
    // c11 = p1 + p4 - p5 + p7

    aResult = p1.add(p3); // p1 + p3
    bResult = aResult.add(p6); // p1 + p3 + p6
    Matrix c22 = bResult.subtract(p2);
    // c22 = p1 + p3 - p2 + p6

    // Grouping the results obtained in a single matrix:
    Matrix result = new Matrix(n, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newSize; j++) {
            result.set(i, j, c11.getVal(i, j));
            result.set(i, j + newSize, c12.getVal(i, j));
            result.set(i + newSize, j, c21.getVal(i, j));
            result.set(i + newSize, j + newSize, c22.getVal(i, j));
        }
    }
    return result;
    }

    public int getSize() {
    return size;
    }
```

Comment: Also fix your identation

Comment: fixed indents and tag

Comment: I suspect that getSize is simply on the top of the stack when it blows up.  Examine the top dozen or so stack frames in the exception traceback and notice the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Strassen multiplication function is missing a base case. At some point, you need to stop recursing and call a different matrix multiplication algorithm.

Comment: Ah yes that would be it. I couldn't for the life of me figure out what would trigger a stack overflow upon calling for a low level integer value. Thanks!

And sorry for the answer edit, hit the wrong button.

Just got it working. Thanks again for the quick help!